# Make panel invisible during Task

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I try to make a panel invisble during an long running task. But it does not work. If I use the compiler than I can see the change of the visible status but not during on the webpage.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="homepage.WoW._default" Async="true" %>
```

Here is my updatepanel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up_mplus" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
 <ContentTemplate>
  <asp:Panel ID="p_test" runat="server">
   <span style="position:absolute; width:calc(100% - 40px); height:25px; text-align:center">Mythic plus Season:&nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_mplus_season" runat="server" BackColor="Transparent" style="color:gainsboro; width:150px; height:21px; top:5px;" OnSelectedIndexChanged ="ddl_mplus_season_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList></span>
    <div id="div_mplus" runat="server" style="width:100%; height:calc(100% - 30px); top:30px"></div> 
 </asp:Panel>
</ContentTemplate>
```

And here is the c# Code behind:

```
protected void btn_reolad_bottom_left_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        testc();
    }

    protected async void testc()
    {
        this.p_test.Visible = false;
        this.up_mplus.Update();
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        });

        this.p_test.Visible =  true;
        this.up_mplus.Update();
    }
```

Comment: The code is running on server and at that point of time, in middle of server side rendering, it doesn't have anything to do with client.  You may want to add a piece of javascript code before sending the ajax request to make the panel invisible and make it visible after the receiving response.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the UI from different threads can cause illegal cross thread operation exception.
You need to invoke it. e.g.:

```
p_test.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => { p_test.Visible = false; }));
```

Comment: Have you noticed to ASP.NET tag?

Comment: You are right. In this case the only thing you can do to use some client side script.